# how to read custom xml tag reader in spring batch-xstream

Tags: xml, spring, spring-batch, xmlreader, xstream

I am new to the spring batch. I have to parse XML to the database using the spring batch process and it works fine if the defined dto has the same values as the XML tags. but when if I have an additional tag that is not defined in dto (i should skip that ) it does not work.

[not working xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49ass.png)

[working xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlmxY.png)

batchconfiguration.java:

```
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.ItemPreparedStatementSetter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxEventItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {
@Autowired
public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
public DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost/springbatch");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("admin");
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public StaxEventItemReader<User> reader() {
    StaxEventItemReader<User> reader = new StaxEventItemReader<User>();
    reader.setResource(new ClassPathResource("user.xml"));
    reader.setFragmentRootElementName("user");

    Map<String, String> aliases = new HashMap<String, String>();
    aliases.put("user", "com.example.demo.User");

    XStreamMarshaller xStreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
    xStreamMarshaller.setAliases(aliases);

    reader.setUnmarshaller(xStreamMarshaller);

    return reader;
}

@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<User> writer() {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<User> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<User>();
    writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
    writer.setSql("insert into user(id,name) values(?, ?)");
    writer.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(new UserItemPreparedStmSetter());

    return writer;
}

private class UserItemPreparedStmSetter implements ItemPreparedStatementSetter<User> {

    @Override
    public void setValues(User user, PreparedStatement ps) throws SQLException {
        ps.setInt(1, user.getId());
        ps.setString(2, user.getName());
    }

}

@Bean
public Step step1() {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<User, User>chunk(10).reader(reader()).writer(writer()).build();
}

@Bean
public Job importUserJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("importUserJob").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer()).flow(step1()).end().build();

}
```

}

Dto:

```
    package com.example.demo;

public class User {
     private Integer id;
     private String name;
     
     public Integer getId() {
      return id;
     }
     public void setId(Integer id) {
      this.id = id;
     }
     public String getName() {
      return name;
     }
     public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
     }
    }
```

Comment: Spring Batch relies on Spring OXM to marshall/unmarshall XML content. In your case, the `StaxEventItemReader` works with a `org.springframework.oxm.Unmarshaller`. So this is not really a Spring Batch question but a XML unmarshalling question (specifically related to xstream since your are using it at implementation). This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11052423/java-xstream-how-to-ignore-some-elements

Comment: thanks, I will try that